How to show tooltip for points with null values in chart js?
I'm using Chart.js to display a line chart with custom tooltips. I have implemented the custom tooltip rendering logic using the external option in the tooltip plugin. However, when there are points with value: null, the external callback is not triggered, and no tooltip is shown for those points.
Here's my current configuration:
plugins: {
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        // other options...
        external: (context) => {
            const { chart, tooltip } = context;
            // my custom tooltip render logic...
        }
    }
}

I've tried various approaches but couldn't find a way to make the external callback fire for null values. Is there any solution or workaround available?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Can you replace the null values with either 0s or average values between the previous and next?

@mplungjan I considered this as a last resort, but it would require hiding those data segments visually and generating their values so that they don't affect the y-axis boundaries of the graph.

As a solution, I stopped using the external callback and instead added an event listener:
chart.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', chartHovering);

In the chartHovering function, I locate the nearest x-axis tick based on the mouse position, then use its datetime to find the corresponding element from the dataset.
After that, I proceed to build my custom tooltip as before.
